# React.js - useRef used in React component instead of DOM object

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I thought I can allocate `useRef` to a React.js component and then have access to the functions in it.
I knew the old way handling `refs` in class components.

There I was able to do something like this:

```
class MyParentComponent extends Component {
...
    render() {
         return (
             <MyComponent
                 ref="myRef"
             />
         )
    }
```

Within this `MyComponent` there is a function called `focus` which focus the first DOM element within `MyComponent` component.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
   ...
   focus() {
      ... //focus first DOM element in component
   }
}
```

That worked fine. I could i.e. do this:

```
class MyParentComponent extends Component {
...
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        this.refs["myRef"].focus();
    }
}
```

This called the function `focus` within the component `MyComponent` - so the first DOM element has got focus.

Now with `useRef` it seems to be more complicated when want to use the `focus` function of `MyComponent`.
Actually the code looks like this:

```
function MyParentComponent(props) {
   ...
   const myRef = useRef(null);
   ...
   return (
       <MyComponent
           ref={myRef}
       />
   )
}
```

But when I want to use this as before, this does not work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.focus();
},[someStateVariableChanged]);
```

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: `myRef.current?.focus();` try this, when you useRef the actual reference is stored under `current`

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add the `current` to add in my code. I'm using it this way already. I found out now, that an error is being thrown (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')`), but IT IS focusing the correct DOM element.

Comment: Yea, the latest answer is correct you have to use `React.forwardRef` if you want to use MyComponent

Answer (score 1):

you should add ref as a dep in useEffect and check if the ref is valid and use `myRef.current`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(myRef.current)
        myRef.current.focus();
}, [someStateVariableChanged, myRef]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ref to a built-in component (like div), not a custom component. If you want to pass a ref to a custom component you need to use `forwardRef`. See https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs